# subtract two string objects pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract two columns in a pandas dataframe they are in the format dd/mm/yyyy I tried doing

```
data['end_date']-data['start_date]
```

but the error returned was: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are treated as strings. You need to convert them to datetime objects:

```
import pandas as pd
data['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end_date'], dayfirst=True)
data['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Then you can do arithmetic operations on dates.